# How to increase the dimension of a matrix in sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, reshape, dimension

Let's say, now I have a 1x1 matrix, like:

```
M = Matrix([[2]])
```

How can I create a new 2x2 matrix from this, filling the all blanks with 0s? Which is:

```
N = Matrix([[2, 0], [0, 0]])
```

If it were numpy, I could use `np.newaxis`; however, it seems that there is no `newaxis` in sympy.

So, I tried:

```
N = M.reshape(2, 2)
```

I got the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid reshape parameters 2 2
```

I found that the following expression works:

```
N = Matrix(2, 2, [D[0], 0, 0, 0])
```

However, this is a bit awkward.
Is there any better way?

Please note that a scalar multiplication `N = D[0] * Matrix(2, 2, [1, 0, 0, 0])` is not acceptable, since next time I may ask you to convert 2x2 to 3x3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sympy.diag`.

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> m = sp.Matrix([[2]])
>>> sp.diag(m, 0)
Matrix([
[2, 0],
[0, 0]])
>>> sp.diag(m, 0, 0)
Matrix([
[2, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0]])
>>> sp.diag(sp.Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]]), 0)
Matrix([
[1, 2, 0],
[3, 4, 0],
[0, 0, 0]])
```